# Why does the function foo cannot return properly?

Tags: c, debugging, recursion, warnings

I am trying to write a recursive function in C programming but the compiler keeps give me warning: control may reach end of non-void function. I don't know where do i get wrong.

```
int foo(int* ptr){
  int flag = 0;
  --(*ptr);
  if((*ptr)!=0) flag = 1;
  if(flag == 0) return 1;
  else foo(ptr);
}

int main()
{
  int count=10;
  int* ptr = &count;

  int n = foo(ptr);
  printf("%d", n);

  return 0;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe a typo, or maybe a misunderstanding, but the last line of your function should be `else return foo(ptr);` (note the added `return`) .

Comment: To return something from a function, you *must* explicitly use the `return` statement. In the `else` branch you recursively call `foo`, but you never actually `return` anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your else statement in function `foo` you are not returning anything.

it should be like this:

```
int foo(int* ptr) {
    int flag = 0;
    --(*ptr);
    if ((*ptr) != 0) 
        flag = 1;
    if (flag == 0) 
        return 1;
    else return foo(ptr);
}
```